# DateTime bug between local machine and remote server - using JodaTime(java 1.8)

Tags: locale, jodatime

I have some code running fine locally but i am getting an error when i run it remotely.

I am unable to debug remotely obviously - but from the error I know it has to with some DateTime Logic (belongs to my code).

I am looking for a comprehensive way to find what's different between my machine and this remote server - and that could affect DateTime logic.

I know Locale - 1/ is there a way to know what is affected by Locale?
2/ Any other local settings that could be different between a local machine and a server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I looked at the FirstDayOfWeek and MinimaldaysinFirstWeek

when I run the following code:
Calendar c1 = new GregorianCalendar();
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault() + ": " + c1.getFirstDayOfWeek() + " " + c1.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.getDefault());
        Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault() + ": " + c.getFirstDayOfWeek() + " " + c.getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());

I got the following output.... It makes no sense...

en_US: 2 4
en_US: 1 1